# jQuery change image onclick

Tags: jquery

Don't know why but I can't find a solution to this. I have 3 links that when clicked I want to change an image below using jQuery. Does anyone know of a really simple script to show me how this might work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Answer can be found [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106980/change-images-using-jquery), though they're using `hover` instead of `click`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<img id="change" src="http://www.nvidia.in/docs/CP/26740/thumbs_googleearth.jpg" />

<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="gog" alt="http://www.nvidia.in/docs/CP/26740/thumbs_googleearth.jpg" >earth</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="gog" alt="http://www.techbusy.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/block-websites-google-search-100x100.jpg" >block</a>
<br>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="gog" alt="http://www.bishanindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/google-plus-l-100x100.jpg" >google plus</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gog").click(function(){
        $("#change").attr("src",$(this).attr("alt"));
    })
})
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrfDc/) ink for the reference